# Hugo: How do you display child pages in a menu specific to a section from your config file?

Tags: hugo

I’m building out a documentation site using Hugo. It has a Main nav and Sidebar nav. After researching I’ve landed on building out my menu using the config file. The menus render correctly, but I’m stuck on how to render my sidebar navigation based on the section I’m in using the config file (see example below).

[Screen shot of page layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMnHy.png)

Here’s my config json. As you can see I’m calling out a single “main” menu, but using “parent” for navigation that would fall under the sidebar nav.

```
{
    "baseURL": "http://example.com/",
    "languageCode": "en-us",
    "title": "DS",
    "menu": {
        "main": [
            {
                "name": "Getting Started",
                "url": "/getting-started",
                "pageRef": "getting-started",
                "weight": 10
            },
            {
                "name": "Contents",
                "url": "/contents",
                "pageRef": "contents",
                "parent": "Getting Started"
            },
            {
                "name": "Download",
                "url": "/download",
                "pageRef": "download",
                "parent": "Getting Started"
            },
            {
                "name": "Foundations",
                "url": "/foundations",
                "pageRef": "foundations",
                "weight": 20
            },
            {
                "name": "Colors",
                "url": "/colors",
                "pageRef": "colors",
                "parent": "Foundations"
            },
            {
                "name": "Grid",
                "url": "/grid",
                "pageRef": "grid",
                "parent": "Foundations"
            },
            {
                "name": "Components",
                "url": "/components",
                "pageRef": "components",
                "weight": 30
            },
            {
                "name": "Alerts",
                "url": "/alerts",
                "pageRef": "alerts",
                "parent": "Components"
            },
            {
                "name": "Badges",
                "url": "/badges",
                "pageRef": "badges",
                "parent": "Components"
            },
            {
                "name": "Utilities",
                "url": "/utilities",
                "pageRef": "utilities",
                "weight": 40
            },
            {
                "name": "Background",
                "url": "/background",
                "pageRef": "background",
                "parent": "Utilities"
            },
            {
                "name": "Borders",
                "url": "/borders",
                "pageRef": "borders",
                "parent": "Utilities"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here’s my code for the Main nav which works great.

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="header__nav">
        <div class="container header__nav-container">
            <div class="header__brand">
                <a href="{{ .Site.BaseURL }}" class="header__brand-type-link">{{ .Site.Title }}</a>
            </div>

            <ul class="header__nav-list">
                {{- $currentPage := . -}} 
                
                {{- range .Site.Menus.main -}}
                <li class="header__nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ .URL }}" class='header__nav-link {{ if or ($currentPage.IsMenuCurrent "main" .) ($currentPage.HasMenuCurrent "main" .) }}current_page_link{{end}}'>{{ .Name }}</a>
                </li>
                {{ end }}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

Here’s the code for my Sidebar nav. This would work great if I didn’t need the navigation to display based on the section you’re in. I have a feeling it has something to to with the .Children in my range. I tried methods like .Site.Section.Children, but that didn’t work. Any thoughts on what I’m missing here?

```
<nav class="sidebar__nav">
    <ul class="sidebar__nav-list">
        {{- $currentPage := . -}} 
        
        {{- range .Site.Menus.main -}}
                {{- range .Children -}}
                <li class="sidebar__nav-item">
                    <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="sidebar__nav-link {{ if $currentPage.IsMenuCurrent `main` . }}current_page_link{{end}}">{{ .Name }}</a>
                </li>
                {{ end }}
        {{ end }}
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could get the section of the current page with `{{ $section := $currentPage.Section }}`, then check if the child menu entry's parent matches the current page's section with `{{- if eq .Parent $section -}}`. I haven't tested this but it should work in theory. You should also probably check if the menu entry itself even has children and if not, only display that as a standalone entry even if it's the current page.

```
<ul class="sidebar__nav-list">
  {{- $currentPage := . -}}
  {{- $section := $currentPage.Section -}}
  {{- range .Site.Menus.main -}}
    {{- if .HasChildren -}}
      <li class="sidebar__nav-item">
        <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="sidebar__nav-link {{ if $currentPage.IsMenuCurrent `main` . }}current_page_link{{end}}">
          {{ .Name }}
        </a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          {{ range .Children }}
            {{- if eq .Parent $section -}}
              <li class="sidebar__nav-item">
                <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="sidebar__nav-link">{{ .Name }}</a>                  
              </li>
            {{ end }}
          {{ end }}
        </ul>
      </li>
    {{ else }}
      <li class="sidebar__nav-item">
        <a href="{{ .URL }}" class="sidebar__nav-link {{ if $currentPage.IsMenuCurrent `main` . }}current_page_link{{end}}">
          {{ .Name }}              
        </a>
      </li>
    {{ end }}
  {{ end }}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I appreciate it. Unfortunately, this only returns the parent pages. The `if` statement for the children does not return results.

Comment: The `{{ if .HasChildren }}` part? That's strange because it works in the theme I developed and is recommended for nested menus on the Hugo docs. The only difference I see is the entries in my default menu config have an `identifier` field which is the lowercased version of `name`. Then the `parent` field in the child entry matches the parent's `identifier`.